# forcing inline functions in gcc with std=c99

Tags: c, gcc, inline

I am writing a pure c code (for fast performance) and I am hoping that gcc can at least expand all the functions that I declared as "static inline" (because I am using std=c99, the semantics of inline has changed and static inline is what preferred), some of those functions include matrix manipulation, heap up/down sift, etc. usually fairly small operations that occurs many time. Is there a way to achieve this by specifying any options of GCC? I have already enabled -o3, and somewhere I came across saying that by -o3 and "static inline" function declaring, all function calls will be expanded. Is that true? How can I verify that? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like cargo-cult programming. Inlining a function does not necessarily mean that program execution will always be faster, consider that expanding a program's size increases the risk of a cache-miss or page-fault and disregards the effect of modern caching and pipelining. I suggest you profile your code to ensure inlining is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Also, there isn't much inherent in other languages, like C++, that behold them to being necessarily always slower than "pure C". If you really care about perf then use assembly.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but you didn't address the questions that I have... please let me know if you have an answer.

Comment: @Dai: There are some embedded system which still do not have caches or MMUs. Most ARM Cortex-M (all M0/+, M3 and far by most M4), for example. Actually, these are the vast majority of CPUs. (Not accoung for the smaller 8 and 16 bit CPUs). And for cache/page-misses: That might be more of a problem without inlining a function.

Comment: Semantics have not changed, as C90 did not have `inline` functions.

Comment: compared with -std=gnu89 ?

Comment: You can fine tune the heuristics GCC uses with arguments like `-finline-limit`, but it's generally better to pass more information about the underlying hardware (`-march`, `--param l1-cache-size`, etc...) and let the compiler decide until you can justify otherwise.

Comment: Semantics for `static inline` have not changed.

Comment: While use GNU extensions myself, they are not standard (obviously). As you stated "... the semantics of inline has changed ..." refering to C99 and wrote you are "writing a pure c code", the reference for the statement would be C90 (gcc did never support C95, iirc). And that does not have inline functions.

Comment: It's all BS that assembly is faster than C and C is faster than C++. Come on guys, have some confidence on your compilers, and people who write them.

Comment: @user3528438 Is there any evidence to suggest that running code using CINT is faster than running code using g++?

Answer (score 1):

You might try `__attribute__((always_inline))`, but in general, normal `inline` should be enough, unless you go for `-Os`. If a function is not inlined, gcc might have good reasons not to.

A better way would be to use profiling and link time optimization (LTO). In general, hand-optimizing code should be the last ressort.

Of course you can verify if a function has been inlined: just look at the generated code.

Comment: i don't want to use "in code" decorator but looking for a gcc option if possible. Thanks!

Comment: I am very sure you do not want to inline **every** function in your code, making it a single giant function. Inlining only makes sense for functions called in time-critical loops. Inlining other functions is just nonsense.

Comment: who said that I want to inline *every* function?

Comment: You did: "Is there a way to achieve this by specifying any options of GCC" and "... but looking for a gcc option ...". Oh, you are not aware that a command line option does apply to all compilation units? How do you think gcc sorts out which are and which are not inlined? (yes, the single function was a bit too much; you would need LTO for that)

Comment: maybe that my thought is wrong.... i think "inline" is only a suggestion to the compiler and what I want to do now is to enforce that those functions declared with "inline" will be expanded by gcc... I thought that by specifying -o3 this can be achieved but I ask here to get confirmed and hopefully someone can point me a way to verify it.

Comment: So I have to smash hope: There is no guarantee a function will be inlined with any `-O?`. But there is one to tag the relevant functions - see my answer. It is much the same as for `register`. And in general, I would leave it to gcc to decide. If your code is still too slow (or you think it is), it's time for profiling. If that is not possible, you might start spreading attributes.

Comment: isn't it true that in c99 for function declared as "static inline", unless accessing this function's address (and maybe few other cases) the function symbol will not be generated? so in that case, i can assume that all the function calls are expanded?

Comment: It's exactly the other way round: If the address is taken, a copy is required. But that does not exclude inlining it elsewhere. There may be more than one copy of such a function (but not in the same CU).